# Test Methods With No Assert result

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, security-scanner, source-scanner

I'm using the Salesforce code scanner to validate my package and am seeing a lot of "Test Methods With No Assert result" messages for methods that do contain asserts, and test methods run successfully.

For example, the below method is asserting that the returned json string contains the data passed in (not a great test I know but it still validates the string).

```
@isTest
public class TokenSSOResponseTests {

@isTest
static void toJsonStringTest() {   

    ResponseStatus respStat = new ResponseStatus();
    respStat.success = true;
    respStat.message = 'this is a test';

    TokenSSOResponse resp = new TokenSSOResponse('testToken', respStat);

    String check = resp.toJsonString(false);
    system.debug('check - ' + check);

    Assert.isTrue(check.contains('testToken'));
 }

 }
```

Why would SF flag this as having no asserts ?

Comment: What is the version of your Code Scanner? There is an old issue that Assert class was not detected: https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/836

Comment: and for those who may wonder, yes, the `Assert` class should be getting detected. [The underlying PMD rule](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-apex/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/apex/rule/bestpractices/ApexUnitTestClassShouldHaveAssertsRule.java) had the `Assert` class methods added on August 17, 2022 and it was included in release 6.49.0 (v3.6.2 of the scanner)